# Can't access Facebook ads via api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to access my Facebook ads information via API and i can't get it to work.
I'm following the documentation from this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account.
This is how my code looks like (Ruby on Rails)

```
def get_ad_set
    access_token = get_access_token
    uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/act_10************31/adsets")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.set_form_data({"fields" => "name", "access_token" => "#{access_token}"})

    response = http.request(request)
end
```

And the response i get is:

"www-authenticate" => 
        [0] "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"Invalid parameter\""

Is it because i don't have the 'Ads Management Basic Access' submitted for the app?
I don't really want the data for public usage, it is only for internal needs.
Do i still have to submit the 'Ads Management Basic Access' item and wait for Facebook to approve it in order to use it?

Comment: if i had to guess, then probably, since that's kind of what "ads management basic access" implies.

Comment: But the error i get seems like it's not about not having access to that certain action, it looks like a general syntax error.

Comment: in your URL.Parse. you forget the api version ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own code and Ruby libraries to perform HTTP calls into Marketing API. As soon as you create an app in your Facebook app dashboard, your app has Development level access, allowing you to call in, however you should have these prerequisites set up before you make calls

- Ad Account
- Page
- an app

If you want to play around making API calls without running ads, you can also use the Developer Sandbox, see https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/10/19/sandbox-ad-accounts/